# Assigning unallocated partition to Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have an unallocated partition of size 200GB
I want to assign it to Ubuntu while installing. How should I do this?

[image: Partitioning]

Answer (score 1):

During install choose custom partitioning. First create a swap-partiton 1 or 2 times the size of your RAM with that unallocated space. Tell the computer to use the swap-partition as swap. Then create a Ext4-partition, tell the computer to use that as / . If u use UEFI than the bootloader should be installed in the 500MB EFI System Partition.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation process it will notice that unallocated space and present you with the option to use just it, or wipe the whole disk.

You do want to make sure it is truly unallocated, that's the only requirement.